# Creating an instance of a class with the same type as an existing object

Tags: c#, base-class

I would like to instantiate an instance of a class based on the type of another instance that is part of a simple type hierarchy.

```
public abstract class Base
{
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
}
```

This is easy to do with the following code

```
Base d1 = new Derived1();

Base d2;

if (d1 is Derived1)
{
    d2 = new Derived1();
}
else if (d1 is Derived2)
{
    d2 = new Derived2();
}
```

However, is it possible to achieve this without an `if...else if...` chain by (for example) using reflection to get hold of the constructor of `d1` (in my example) and using it to instantiate another instance of whatever type `d1` might happen to be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
d2 = (Base)Activator.CreateInstance(d1.GetType());
```

Comment: I had just figured this out and was about to answer or delete my question... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Factory Method design pattern:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract Base New();
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public override Base New()
    {
        return new Derived1();
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public override Base New()
    {
        return new Derived2();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Base d1 = new Derived1();
Base d2 = d1.New();
```

More effort than reflection but also more portable and faster.

Comment: I had used this previously, but it seemed like a lot (OK, not really that much...) of unnecessary code. What do you mean by portable? Have you got any metrics to illustrate the performance difference?

Comment: @RichardEv I don't have metrics. However I checked the two on my machine and the difference exists, but is negligible. Maybe for more types and more complex environment without any compiler optimisations, that difference could grow. I safely assume, that code based on inheritance is more efficient than its counterpart based on reflection.