# C# Instantiate a base object as a derived object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a situation where I have an abstract base class object being used as a placeholder to instantiate a derived object... for example...

```
public abstract class Fruit(){ //stuff}

public class Banana() : Fruit(){ //stuff }

public class Apple() : Fruit(){ //stuff }

public class FruitSalad() 
{
 Fruit SomeKindOfFruit;
 public DoStuff(Fruit frt)
 { 
   SomeKindOfFruit = new ?????
 }
}
```

So, the function is going to accept a fruit... the program doesn't know what kind of fruit... could be an Apple... could be a Banana... could be a Kiwi... but I need it to take the input frt and then tell SomeKindOfFruit, "Hey.. frt is an Apple, so you are now an Apple".

I know that SomeKindOfFruit = new Apple(); works... but what I don't want to have to do is have to hardcode a bunch of if/then statements or a switch to evaluate the type and then explicitly declare every possible derived class... and derived classes of those derived classes... and derived classes of the derived classes of... ad nauseum... especially since to even do that I have to pull the type anyway to even evaluate it and it would be so much easier to just be able to say, "See this derived thing?  Whatever this thing is, you are now that type of thing".  Just one piece of code so I can create as many derived classes as I want and it'll just keep working; I don't have to go in repeatedly to add more evaluations.

[EDIT]

That is what I thought... and I initially tried to just do a simple equals equation... and it throws a null reference exception.  Ok, so what I'm actually  doing has nothing to do with fruit, but that was the simplest way of describing the issue without getting lost in the weeds.  What the actual program is doing is I have 2 classes... well, one class that runs a GUI component and a set of classes (base + derived classes) that is all the data types that are being manipulated under the hood and across the network.  Within each of those classes I have created object that, in theory are supposed to reference eachother.  The sequence is that a data class is created from stored SQL data.  Once all the data is created, I have a method in the data class that creates the graphic class that will display it on GUI.  Part of that is that the data class is supposed to give the graphics class a refence to itself, so that both classes have references to the other and information can go both ways... I can send information through the graphics components into its relevant data class and the data class can take information from the net and display it graphically

```
public abstract class baseData() {
public graphicClass GraphicRepresentation;

     public baseData(stuff){
     //Sets all the relevant data
     }

     public void Activate(){
     GraphicRepresentation = new graphicClass();
     //Sets all the relevant components in the class
     GraphicRepresentation.DataReference = this;
     }`
  }
```

The above throws a null reference exception.  The only thing I can think of is that DataReference, which is a baseData object, needs to be instantiated before I can assign "this" to it, but I can't instantiate an abstract class, so I have to be able to instantiate it as whatever derived type "this" is before I can make it equal to "this".

Comment: `SomeKindOfFruit = frt`???? Not very clear why that does not work.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question if you found the issue. Just explain your findings in a comment and flag your question as off-topic -> typo. I rolled back to your original question.

Comment: I'm voting to close as typo because of the OP's explanation in [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38669603/3).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an instance of a class with the same type as an existing object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127495/creating-an-instance-of-a-class-with-the-same-type-as-an-existing-object)

Answer (score 2):

You could make your method generic:

```
public class FruitSalad() 
{
    Fruit SomeKindOfFruit;

    public DoStuff<TFruit>(TFruit frt)
        where TFruit : Fruit, new()
    {
        SomeeKindOfFruit = new TFruit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point.

Firstly, your `DoStuff` method suggests a [temporary field code smell](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/18/temporary-field-code-smell/). Class fields are meant to be initialised in the constructor and not in methods. If I were to implement the `FruitSalad` class, I would probably write it like:

```
public class FruitSalad
{
    private readonly Fruit _fruit;

    public FruitSalad(Fruit fruit)
    {
        _fruit = fruit;
    }

    public DoStuff()
    {
        // Act on the _fruit field
    }
}
```

Secondly, It doesn't matter what is the actual runtime type of `Fruit` being passed into the constructor/`DoStuff` method of `FruitSalad` as long as it is derived from `Fruit`. This is **[polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))**.

For example, if there were an `abstract` method `CutToPieces` in `Fruit` like:

```
public abstract class Fruit
{
    public abstract void CutToPieces();
}
```

with `Apple` and `Banana` being implemented like:

```
public class Apple : Fruit
{
    public override void CutToPieces()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Apple being diced");
    }
}

public class Banana : Fruit
{
    public override void CutToPieces()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Banana being cut to small pieces");
    }
}
```

Your `FruitSalad` can still be prepared without knowing the actual runtime type of the `Fruit` instance being passed in:

```
public class FruitSalad
{
    private readonly Fruit _fruit;

    public FruitSalad(Fruit fruit)
    {
        _fruit = fruit;
    }

    public DoStuff()
    {
        // Prints "Apple being diced" or "Banana being cut to small pieces"
        // depending on the runtime type of `Fruit` being passed into the 
        // constructor of FruitSalad
        _fruit.CutToPieces();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added more info.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR already has a facility for this:

```
void GetFruitType(Fruit fruit)
{
    Type t = fruit.GetType();
    if (t.Equals(typeof(Apple))) HandleApple();
}
```

However if you want to avoid handling the guessing and switching through all types, you should use composition instead of inheritance:

```
interface IFruit
{
    void CutFruit();
}


class Apple : IFruit
{
    public void IFruit.CutFruit()
    {
        // Implementation for apple
        // For fruits that do not support cutting, you still need to
        // implement the interface, but you can throw a NotSupportedException
        // and then catch the exception in the FruitSalad class
    }
}

class Grape : IFruit
{
    public void IFruit.CutFruit()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("You don't cut grapes...");
    }   
}

class FruitSalad
{
    IFruit[] _fruits = null; // Initialize in constructor or through property

    void CutFruits()
    {
        foreach (IFruit fruit in _fruits)
        {
            try
            {
                fruit.CutFruit();
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Composition seems like a better choice here, it shortens the inheritance chain and keeps fruit-specific implementation in the derived class. Single responsibility principle and all that.